# Probability of international travel

Tags: probability

The following is a probability question I got during an interview:

I had two travels in the last year. At least one of them is an international travel in December, what is the probability that both travels are international? The probability of traveling in one specific month is $\frac {1}{12}$, and the probability of an international travel is $\frac {1}{2}$. Each trip is independent.

The correct answer is $\frac {23}{47}$, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as worded is a bit ambiguous, but looking at the answer, we can consider the following problem.

> Imagine $24$ balls organized into $12$ bins; in each bin there is one red ball (representing an international trip) and a green ball (representing a non-international trip). You draw $2$ balls at random, with replacement, and observe that at least one of them is red and from bin $12$. What is the probability that the other ball is red?

First, we compute the number of draws that yield at least one red ball from bin $12$. If the ball was drawn first, then there are $24$ choices for the second ball. If the ball was drawn second, there are also $24$ choices for the first ball. But we have overcounted $1$ drawing, which is where the red ball from bin $12$ was drawn twice. Therefore, there are $(2) (24) - 1 = 47$ equally-likely drawings that satisfy the required condition.

Now, we compute the number of these drawings where both drawn balls are red. This works in basically the same way: if the red ball from bin $12$ was drawn first, there are $12$ ways to choose a red ball for the second drawing; if the red ball from bin $12$ was drawn second, there are $12$ ways to choose a red ball for the first drawing. But we have overcounted by $1$ where both draws are the red ball from bin $12$. So, the number of "successful" drawings is $(2) (12) - 1 = 23$.

The desired probability is therefore $\frac{23}{47}$.